# cant find the token on the logcat android studios

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

its me, again. I can't seem to find the token for my app even if its already connected to firebase.
any form of help will be very much appreciated.

**Below are the codes**

**MyFirebaseIdservice Class**

```
package com.lrtapp.ardentmap;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Map;

public class MyFirebaseIdService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.

        super.onNewToken(s);
        //String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().getResult().getToken();
        Log.d("New_Token", s);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(params);
        Log.e("JSON_OBJECT", object.toString());

        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "EaseRoute_Channel";

        long pattern[] = {0, 1000, 500, 1000};

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel mChannel =
                    new NotificationChannel(Constants.CHANNEL_ID, Constants.CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            mChannel.setDescription(Constants.CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION);
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);

            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400 ,500 ,400, 300, 200, 400});

            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.BASE){
            NotificationChannel channel = mNotificationManager.getNotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            channel.canBypassDnd();
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent))
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setAutoCancel(true);


        mNotificationManager.notify(1000, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

**My MainActivity Class**

```
package com.lrtapp.ardentmap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;

    private Button btnAbout;
    private Button btnContact;
    private Button btnVideos;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnAbout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAbout);
        btnAbout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openAbout();
            }
        });

        btnContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnContact);
        btnContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                openContact();
            }
        });

        btnVideos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVideos);
        btnVideos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                openVideos();
            }
        });


       // common.currentToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().getResult().getToken();

        //Log.d("My Token", common.currentToken);

        if(isServicesOK())

            init();
    }

    private void init(){

        Button btnMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMap);
        btnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isServicesOK(){
        Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: checking google services version");

        int available = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(MainActivity.this);

        if(available == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            //everything is okay
            Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: Google Play services is working");
            return true;
        }else if(GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isUserResolvableError(available)){
            // an error occured but we can resolve it
            Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: an error occured but we can fix it");
            Dialog dialog = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(MainActivity.this, available, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "we cant make map requests", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void openAbout(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openContact(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Contact.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openVideos(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Videos.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

**My Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lrtapp.ardentmap">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/erlogo"
        android:label="EaseRoute"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyALC_Pis5w391INiqcvnXO7dipxuMP0-JA" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MapActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".About" />
        <activity android:name=".Contact" />
        <activity android:name=".Videos"></activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>


        <service
            android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:stopWithTask="false">
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>



        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent"/>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Project Gradle**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lrtapp.ardentmap">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/erlogo"
        android:label="EaseRoute"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyALC_Pis5w391INiqcvnXO7dipxuMP0-JA" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MapActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".About" />
        <activity android:name=".Contact" />
        <activity android:name=".Videos"></activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>


        <service
            android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:stopWithTask="false">
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>



        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent"/>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

**module gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Thank you in advance to those who will answer or respond. Good day / night to you!

Answer (score 0):

Override `onNewToken(String)` on your `FirebaseMessagingService` class:

```
@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {
    super.onNewToken(token);
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: actually, mine was like that moments ago. and it was deprecated on my android studio.

Answer (score 0):

onNewToken is called only when a new token is generated. Firebase doesn't create a new token every time you open the app. In your MainActivity's onCreate add

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {                    
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                  String token = instanceIdResult.getToken();
                  Log.d("MyFirebaseToken", token);

            }});
```

Comment: So i can use the first token that was generated? But why cant i receive notifications still?

Comment: Use the above method and get whatever the latest token Is. Then use that

Comment: Also, how are you testing your notification?

Comment: Through firebase console, im pasting the token on the firebase console, i followed a youtube tutorial

Comment: And oh, btw im testing it on a real device. My ram couldnt handle the emulator

Comment: It's always better to test push notifications on a real device. I haven't heard of firebase console providing test for fcm. Can you share the link. or the video

Comment: Here it is, its kind of at the end of the video.

Comment: and you are not receiving the notification?

Comment: Yes, im not receiving it. But i havent tried what you posted yet, im trying to get my eyes some rest right now haha